# Parse XML response

Tags: php, curl

How can i parse the xml response with curl to get specific data and display it as html

Actual code :

```
$xmlRQ = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SearchAvailabilityRQ version="2.0" language="SPA">
          <Request>
            <DestinationID>69152</DestinationID>
            <Check_in_date>2020-10-13</Check_in_date>
            <Check_out_date>2020-10-16</Check_out_date>
          </Request>
        </SearchAvailabilityRQ>';
$post_data = array(.....);
$URL = "***";
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo ($output);
```

This is the [response sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20fEQ.png)

Comment: Possibly [simplexml](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) will help you to parse the responce. Curl itself has nothing to do with parsing